# Java Philosopher diner

Tags: java, multithreading, dining-philosopher

I have been working on the philosopher dinning task and I have a problem, my code revolves around 3 classes, Forks, philosophers and dinerTable (yes I named the last two with small letters by mistake).

The code starts properly, philosopher 0 and 2 grab their forks, but then the code just stops, can anyone help me please?

There are the 3 classes :

Forks (extends Thread) :

```
public synchronized boolean isFree() throws InterruptedException
{
    return available;

}

public synchronized void returnFork() throws InterruptedException
{
    available = true;
    this.notify();
}

public synchronized void takeFork() throws InterruptedException
{
    available = false;
    this.notify();
}
```

philosophers (implements Runnable) :

```
    private int number;
private Forks right;
private Forks left;
private boolean hasBothForks;
private boolean keepGoing;

public boolean isKeepGoing() {
    return keepGoing;
}

public void setKeepGoing(boolean keepGoing) {
    this.keepGoing = keepGoing;
}

public philosophers(int number,Forks right, Forks left, boolean keepGoing)
{
    this.number = number;
    this.right = right;
    this.left = left;
    hasBothForks = false;
    this.keepGoing = keepGoing;
}

private void print(String message)
{
    System.out.println("Philosopher " + number + " " + message );

}

@Override
public void run() {
    if(keepGoing == true)
    {
        try
        {


            print("is hungry");
            print( "checks if forks are free");
            if(right.isFree() == true && left.isFree() == true && hasBothForks == false)
            {
                print("is grabbing forks");
                right.takeFork();
                left.takeFork();
                hasBothForks = true;
            } // end if
            else if(hasBothForks == true)
            {
                print("is eating");
                Thread.sleep(2000);
                print("is putting down left fork");
                left.returnFork();
                print("is putting down right fork");
                right.returnFork();
                print("is finished eating");
                hasBothForks = false;
            } // end if
            else if(right.isFree() == false && left.isFree() == false && hasBothForks == false)
                {
                    print("is thinking");
                    Thread.sleep(2000);
                } // end if             

        } // end try
        catch (InterruptedException e) {

                    print(" is interrupted");

        } // end catch
    } // end if


} // end run
```

dinerTable :

```
private static int num = 5;
private static Forks right = null;
private static Forks left = null;
private static Forks[] forks = new Forks[num];
private static philosophers[] philosophers = new philosophers[num];

public static void main(String args[])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < num ; i++)
    {
        forks[i] = new Forks();
    }
        for (int i = 0; i < num; i++)
        {
            if (i > 0)
            {
                left = forks[i - 1];
                right = forks[i];
            } // end if
            else if ( i == 0)
            {
                left = forks[num-1];
                right = forks[i];
            } // end if

            philosophers[i] = new philosophers(i, right, left, true);

            Thread thread = new Thread(philosophers[i]);
            thread.start();

        } // end for

        System.out.print("\n");
}
```

Comment: Your IDE can refactor the class names into the correct casing

Comment: I don't want to be mean, but you neither told me how to do that, nor did you help me with my issue, however, thank you for the tip

Comment: jvisualvm can help you monitor threads. Your main process does not consider the situation where only one fork is free. It is also possible for a philosopher to think a fork is free, you also have a race condition with the forks.

Comment: @user2189708 each ide does it in a different way. So @Thorbjørn Ravn Andersen cannot tell you how to do it without knowing which ide you are using, only pointing out you can. It will usually be called `refactor` maybe `right clicking` or look for a menu that says `source` or `code`

Comment: @BevynQ why would a philosopher think it is free?

Comment: Ok, I'm using eclipse, main thing is this question is related to the threading thing, nothing else, that would be another question, I'm pretty sure the rules themselves say to only talk about the question. Back to subject, the philosopher needs both to be available to eat, that's why I have a test for both, also what do you mean that it is possible to think it is free, do you mean he might mistake a free one for one which is not free? How is that possible, I set them each time. Race condition? Can I get some sort of tangible advice? Regarding my issue? Which I asked about?

Comment: Fixed philosophers from if(keepGoing == true) to while, but now I'm in a deadlock to checking if forks are free

Comment: A couple of questions to help me understand the code a bit before offering an answer.  Why does the `Forks` class need to extend `Thread` if it's never being run?  In the `Forks` class, both the `returnFork` and `takeFork` methods are calling notify.  Typically in this kind of situation, one of those would be calling `wait` and the other would be calling `notify` or `notifyAll`.  Was this a mistake?

Comment: It was a mistake because it is my first time trying to make something with threading, I've been reading on oracle documentation but I still have some lacks in my knowledge about this

Comment: @Nikola the locking is at method level so state, can change between method calls. You need to aquire a lock that wraps both method calls. In this case two philosphers can grab the same fork.

Comment: @user2189708 that is why it was a comment, not an answer.  In eclipse right click the class and find the rename refactoring.  Keeping to established conventions is important because it makes your program easier to read later.

Comment: @Thorbjørn Ravn Andersen, I'm sorry if I seemed rude or anything, I was just a bit frustrated over this problem since I never used threads before. However, thank you again for the tip, I actually used it to rename some of the classes from my old projects where I mistyped the name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After changing the `if` to a `while` in the `run` method of philosopher, try updating the `Forks` functions for take and return as follows:

```
public synchronized void returnFork() throws InterruptedException
{
    available = true;
    this.notifyAll();
}

public synchronized void takeFork() throws InterruptedException
{
    while(!available){
      this.wait();
    }
    available = false;
}
```

I then made a couple of tweaks in the `run` method of philosophers as follows:

```
      if (!hasBothForks){
        print("is hungry");
        print( "checks if forks are free");            
      }

      if(right.isFree() == true && left.isFree() == true && hasBothForks == false)
      {
          print("is grabbing forks");
          right.takeFork();
          left.takeFork();
          hasBothForks = true;
      } // end if
      else if(hasBothForks == true)
      {
          print("is eating");
          Thread.sleep(2000);
          print("is putting down left fork");
          left.returnFork();
          print("is putting down right fork");
          right.returnFork();
          print("is finished eating");
          hasBothForks = false;
      } // end if
      else if((right.isFree() == false || left.isFree() == false) && hasBothForks == false)
          {
              print("is thinking");
              Thread.sleep(2000);
          } // end if
```

With these two sets of changes I see the output flow much better.  Still not sure if it's exactly what you want though.

Comment: they are stopped in an inf loop now, no one is taking the forks :?

Comment: I want for the program to be free of deadlock, eventually though, yours also gets deadlock

Comment: I added a justAte check for the ones that just used the forks, works now, still, you were the most helpful, thank you

Answer (score 2):

I am posting this an answer as I cannot post comments.

The initial problem with this is that there is no thread synchronisation. it is possible for *ALL* of the philosophers to obtain both forks because of a race condition.

```
if(right.isFree() == true && left.isFree() == true && hasBothForks == false)
{
    print("is grabbing forks");
    right.takeFork();
    left.takeFork();
    hasBothForks = true;
}
```

if it happens in this order:

```
P1: right.isFree() == true, left.isFree() == true, hasBothForks == false - thread is slept by the scheduler
P2: right.isFree() == true, left.isFree() == true, hasBothForks == false - thread is slept by the scheduler
P3: right.isFree() == true, left.isFree() == true, hasBothForks == false - thread is slept by the scheduler
P4: right.isFree() == true, left.isFree() == true, hasBothForks == false - thread is slept by the scheduler
P5: right.isFree() == true, left.isFree() == true, hasBothForks == false - thread is slept by the scheduler

P1: right.takeFork(), left.takeFork() - thread is slept by the scheduler
P2: right.takeFork(), left.takeFork() - thread is slept by the scheduler
P3: right.takeFork(), left.takeFork() - thread is slept by the scheduler
P4: right.takeFork(), left.takeFork() - thread is slept by the scheduler
P5: right.takeFork(), left.takeFork() - thread is slept by the scheduler
```

**EDIT:**

The solution to this threading problem is two fold.

Firstly the fork are actually meant to be a thread safe object known as a [Mutex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutex) or [Semaphore](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semaphore_%28programming%29). This means that only 1 token is available per fork and the other people requesting this fork must wait until it is available.

Secondly you need a way for the philosophers to not all go for the left fork first, or all go for the right fork first as this can cause starvation. Instead you need to come up with a solution such as making odd numbered philosophers be left handed (grab left fork first) and even number philosophers right handed (grab right fork first).

With these two issues fixed you should always have at least 1 philosopher who is able to be eating, and once he is finished eating releases both Forks (read semaphores) and allows other philosophers to acquire the forks.

**EDIT 2:**

A good in depth explanation of the solution I suggested is available at: http://www.cs.mtu.edu/~shene/NSF-3/e-Book/MUTEX/TM-example-left-right.html

Comment: I assumed calling synchronized on the method would ensure that the method isn t called again until another thread is finished with it, how else can I sync?

Comment: The issue method calls themselves are synchronized, but this is happening after the if condition check (which is after all of the method calls)

Comment: so how can I sync them there?

Comment: see my edit, I explained the two issues at play. If you need to implement the semaphores (thread-safe locking functionality) you will need to look into how they are operated, see link.

Comment: Thank you, with your help and @cmbaxter I managed to get it to work